# Как выполнить звонок в фоне?

Tags: android

На Хабре нашел [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/130717/) про отправку USSD запроса, там используется Activity, а мне бы хотелось отправить и получить ответ в фоновом режиме, что бы не появлялся экран набора номера, и потом не вылазил Alert с текстом сообщения. Пытался сделать сервис, но не получилось, точнее я не могу точно сказать получилось или нет, отправить то он может и отправил, а вот как ответ получить я не смог разобраться, прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Вызвать StartActivityForResult можно только из Activity. Поэтому впрямую метод, описанный на Хабре неприменим для служб. Можно попробовать

1. создать вспомогательную активность и посылать-принимать запросы через нее,
2. просить запрашиваемые активности рассылать результаты через Broadcast Intent.